# apache fileupload parserequest doesn't return filelist

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to expose REST service for file upload and write REST client to call the service. Am using apache fileupload to consume the file as my current application is old and belongs to servlet api era of 2.5. When I call parseRequest method of ServletFileUpload, it doesn't return any files from the request and throws Error object. This application also supports Spring 4.

Rest Client

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

parts.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()));
parts.add("path", "C:/Temp/link.txt");

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
headers.setContentDispositionFormData("filename","link.txt");

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parts, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:9080/contextroot/restservice.htm",requestEntity, String.class);
```

Servlet Rest Service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "restservice.htm")
public ResponseMessage restservice(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException, FileUploadException {



    if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List<FileItem> fileList = upload.parseRequest(request);

        System.out.println("Headers : ");
        Enumeration<String> headerEnumeration = request.getHeaderNames();
        while(headerEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = headerEnumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Name : " + headerName + ", Value : " + request.getHeader(headerName));
        }

        System.out.println("Parameters : ");
        Enumeration<String> paramEnumeration = request.getParameterNames();
        while(paramEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = paramEnumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Name : " + paramName + ", Value : " + request.getParameter(paramName));
        }

        if(null == fileList || fileList.isEmpty()) {
            //Setting ERROR
        }
        else {
            //Setting SUCCESS
        }
    }
    else {
            //Setting ERROR
    }


    return message;
}
```

And the output for header is

```
Name : Accept, Value : text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*
Name : Content-Type, Value : multipart/form-  data;boundary=CqVx3AfV3oq7XjEPmPkWXqve9lNs3Ntjhz1kBaI
Name : Content-Disposition, Value : form-data; name="filename"; filename="link.txt"
```

Request parameter contains both path and file references.

Comment: Normally you'd post the error message. It's hard to help you when you say just say it "throws Error object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created object with XMLRootElement and sent the file reference within the object. The consuming REST service was quick to pick the file reference.

REST client

```
 File srcFile = new File("C:/Temp/hellotest.jpg");
 FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
 byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);               
 inputStream.close();
 FileInfo requestEntity = new FileInfo();
 requestEntity.setPath("C:/Temp/hellotest12.jpg");
 requestEntity.setContent(bytes);
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();                
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:9080/contextroot/restservice.htm",requestEntity, String.class);
```

REST Service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "restservice.htm")
public String restservice(@RequestBody FileInfo fileInfo, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
    LOG.info("File created @ " + fileInfo.getPath());
    File file = new File(fileInfo.getPath());

    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    IOUtils.write(fileInfo.getContent(), outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();


     return message;
}
```